# Adding 1st/3rd quartile and 90th percentile to a line chart in R

Tags: r

The title says it all. What I would like to do is plotting the median, but also displaying the two quartiles as well as the 90th percentile at each timepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a small sample dataset with observations `y` for 3 timepoints `time` (100 observations for each timepoint).

> dd <- data.frame(y=c(rnorm(100, 10, 2), rnorm(100, 15, 2), rnorm(100, 20,2)),
>            time=rep(c(1,2,3), each=100))

Next, summarizing you data according to what you want (here only median and first quantile, but the principle is the same to obtain other quantiles)

> dd1 <- ddply(dd, "time", summarise, 
>           med=median(y),
>           firstquart=quantile(y, probs=.01))

Finally, plotting your lines with `ggplot` - first quantile is in red.

> ggplot(dd1, aes(x=time, y=med)) + geom_line()+geom_line(aes(x=time, y=firstquart), colour="red")

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work! How would you have to change it if you don't want the three percentiles to be separate lines but vertical ones at each time point (like error bars)?